# How good are Aeroflot's current safety and performance standards?

Tags: air-travel, safety, airlines, aeroflot

[Aeroflot has historically had a poor safety record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroflot_accidents_and_incidents) with over 100 reported accidents and fatalities running into thousands. It seems, however, that these petered out towards the mid-90s. How good is Aeroflot's current safety record as far as incidents related to passengers getting harmed, technical failures etc are considered? Anecdotal experiences as well as authoritative sources would be useful.

Also, if it's possible to know, how good is Aeroflot's on-time performance?

Comment: I travelled once with them. One thing to consider: The staff(pilots and stewardesses) speak bad English. They first say the announcement in Russian and them mumble/translate it in English, stopping halfway through). I could barely order something cause the steward didn't get me. Another issue that scared me a little: a few drops of condensed water falling on my head.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends a lot on where you're flying.  Also Aeroflot was a different airline pre 1991, when it got broken up into all the subsidiary ex-Soviet state airlines.  So I'd concentrate on after that, as it also affected maintenance standards and the like.

As far as timeliness of flights goes, it depends on your flight - but [Flightstats has the details](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightRating/flightRatingByCarrier.do?airlineCode=SU).  Overall 76% are on time.  7% are 'excessively late'.

You also have to realise how BIG Aeroflot used to be before the breakup in 1991.  Sure it had about 3 crashes every year, but it was also huge.  A [discussion of the realities behind these statistics](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/read.main/512619/) is quite an informative and interesting read.

Finally, a blog post "[How to survive Aeroflot](http://finaltransit.com/blog/how-to-survive-aeroflot/)".  Worth a look if you're considering flying with them.

Comment: I tend to disagree with that part where you say that there are lots of accidents because Aeroflot is BIG. I heard somewhere that Aeroflot and Lufthansa were established almost at the same, their size was almost the same but Aeroflot has several times more fatalities. Unfortunately I was not able to find sources right now.

Comment: http://www.airdisaster.com/cgi-bin/airline_detail.cgi?airline=Lufthansa vs http://www.airdisaster.com/cgi-bin/airline_detail.cgi?airline=Aeroflot

Comment: Not *because* it's big, just to be aware that it used to be waaaaay bigger than it is now - many of the national carriers of Kazakhstan, Kyrgyzstan and others used to be part of Aeroflot.  Size obviously still doesn't excuse crashes, of course.

Comment: Aeroflot was far larger than Lufthansa ever was, what with every single civilian and many military (passenger/transport) aircraft being listed under its registry. As such, many things unrelated to passenger transport and far more likely to cause accidents were on paper Aeroflot, like supply flights in the Afghan war, cropdusters, resupply flights of offshore oil and gas rigs, polar stations, etc. etc.

Answer (score 11):

Last accident was at 2008 ([more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroflot_Flight_821)) and it actually happened with their subsidiary company. There is great difference between domestic and international flights, second are much better both in terms of service and safety. I flew from Russia to NYC for 650$ and everything was perfect, I expected much worse.